# Duals of Convex Isohedra are Uniform?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, convex-geometry

All of the convex isohedra are either Platonic, Catalan, bipyramids, or trapezohedra. Their duals are Platonic, Archimedean, prisms, or antiprisms respectively, all of which are uniform, i.e. having each face a regular polygon.

Why does every convex isohedron have a uniform dual? Is there a good explanation of this, other than exhausting this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"iso" sometimes is being mixed up with "equi". Both meaning "same". Wrt. facial shapes (isohedra/equihedra) resp. vertex figures (isogonal/equigonal polyhedron) those clearly ask for congruence of the respective shape, i.e. is more a local comparation of local patches. But "iso" additionally includes some symmetry transitivity too, i.e. kind of is a global comparation. E.g. the [Miller polyhedron J37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola) well is equigonal (all are of type 3,4,4,4) but is not isogonal (polar and tropal vertices cannot be interchanged by global symmetry).

Using this distinction then it becomes evident that the duals of (truely) isohedral polyhedra would indeed be isogonal, i.e. have a symmetry group which acts on the vertex transitive. But the latter description is just *one* of the requirements for [uniform polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron). Additionally there is the requirement for unit edges throughout (which thus ensures regular polygonal (or regular polygrammal) faces only. (And for uniform *polytopes* (of arbitrary dimension) even dimensional hierarchical application is required as well, where (for induction start) the uniform polygons are just the regular polygons.) - Those *further additions* clearly cannot be ensured by solely isohedral preimages.

--- rk

Comment: I agree that the unit edge requirement doesn't seem to be follow in an obvious way from isohedral dual the same way isogonal does, but at least in the convex 3D case, it seems to follow anyway, which is my question. Why does this more obscurely-related property still follow, at least for convex polyhedra? Or perhaps I am mistaken and there is a convex isohedron with dual that does not have unit-edges.

Comment: Dualization is usually being done by means of spherical reciprocation. So take a digonal antiprism, its insphere, thus the dual will be obtained as the convex hull of the tangent points. Obviously, if you have started with a longuish digonal antiprism, which clearly is a convex isohedron, the dual would become a rather shallow digonal antiprism. Thus its edges will clearly differ, at least between the 2 polar edges (degenerate antiprism bases) and the 4 lacing zigzag ones.

Comment: I see. So [this list of isohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohedral_figure) is incomplete because it lacks the long digonal antiprism, which is a stretched tetrahedron. However, this list doesn't require equal edge lengths, since it has the triakis tetrahedron, among others. So is this some instance where the duals of the isohedra can be made uniform via some linear transformation of the space? I'm just wondering in what sense their classification of isohedra is correct, if it is at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not every convex isohedron has a uniform dual. The dual of a bipyramid or trapezohedron is always a prism or antiprism, respectively, but is usually not uniform.